# Probability with people

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory

Experience shows that 20% of the people reserving tables at a certain restaurant never show up. If the restaurant has 50 tables and takes 52 reservations, what is the probability that it will be able to accomodate everyone?

I tried to solve this problem but am not sure how to do this. I tried saying that since 20% of people never show up then 80% of them do. I also said that we can subtract it from 1 since they are trying to accomodate everyone. Here is my working.

$1-(80/100)^{51}$ $(1/4)^{52}$

Can someone please help me. Please show and explain how I can correct this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re to interpret the statement that $20$% of those who reserve tables never show up to mean that the probability that someone who reserves a table fails to show up is $\frac15$; the probability that someone who reserves a table **does** show up is then $1-\frac15=\frac45$.

Your idea of computing the probability that the restaurant will **not** be able to accommodate everyone and subtracting that from $1$ is good, but you calculated that probability incorrectly. In particular, I’ve no idea where the $\left(\frac14\right)^{52}$ came from.

There are two ways in which the restaurant can be in trouble: $51$ people show up, or all $52$ show up.

- The probability that all $52$ show up is $\left(\frac45\right)^{52}$.
- The probability that **a particular set of** $51$ people shows up and the $52$-nd person does not is $\left(\frac45\right)^{51}\left(\frac15\right)$. However, there are $\binom{52}{51}=52$ different sets of $51$ that could show up, so the probability that **some** set of $51$ shows up and the $52$-nd person does not is $52\left(\frac45\right)^{51}\left(\frac15\right)$.

What should you do with these two probabilities in order to complete the problem?

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say (1/5) not $(1/4)^{52}$

Comment: @9599: In that case your main problem is that you’re not taking into account all of the ways in which too many customers can show up; you’re counting only some of them.

Comment: Is the solution $1$ $-$ $4/5^{52}$ $-$ $\binom{51}{1}$ $(4/5)^{51}$ $(1/5)$.

Comment: @9599: Not quite: the binomial coefficient should be $\binom{52}{51}$ or $\binom{52}1$, depending on whether you’re thinking of choosing which $51$ show up or which one doesn’t. (The $51$ in the last line of my second bullet point was a typo, which I’ve now fixed.) Oh, and I presume that the middle term is really $(4/5)^{52}$, not $4/5^{52}=\frac4{5^{52}}$.

Comment: Yes the middle term is $(4/5)^{52}$. Sorry I am learning how to type in latex. Yes I meant to put a 52 there.

Comment: @9599: $(1/5)^{52}$ is the probability that none of the customers shows up. In general the probability that a particular set of $k$ customers shows up and the other $52-k$ don’t is $(4/5)^k(1/5)^{n-k}$, with one factor for each customer. There are $\binom{52}k$ sets of $k$ customers, so the probability that exactly $k$ customers show up is $\binom{52}k(4/5)^k(1/5)^{n-k}$: we have to add together the probabilities for the $\binom{52}k$ possible ways in which this can happen. (You’re doing fine with the $\LaTeX$; it takes a while.)

Comment: @9599: That’s fine for the probability that exactly $51$ show up: you can use either $\binom{52}{51}$, counting the number of possible sets of $51$ who do show, or $\binom{52}1$, counting the number of possible individuals who don’t show. They’re both $52$.

Comment: Ok. I see. Thanks Brian. You were great help. I might contact you for other problems. I am going to vote your answer.

Comment: @9599: You’re welcome; glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

The probabilty would be 1 since we are considering that out of 52 people who make reservations, 20% do not show up, there for 10 people will not show up, which leaves 42 people who reserved their tables being accommodated. This, of course is only true if the 20% of people not showing up is always the case

Comment: This OP means to say that each reservation has an independent 80% chance of showing up.  (This is, incidentally, a much more realistic model than your model - I would be very surprised if the number of people showing up were always exactly 80%.)

Comment: If the OP meant to say that each reservation has an independent 80% chance of showing up, then the OP should have said that.  This is a correct answer to the OP's actual question.

Answer (score 0):

$50$ tables can accommodate $50$ men. But they have taken $52$ reservations.

The restaurant will be able to accommodate everyone, if 50 men or fewer men show up.
Everyone gets a seat when $(X \leq 50)$.
To find this, we use the complement rule.
$1 -$ [Find the chance, Too many men show up with $X = 51$ OR $X = 52$]

Given : 20% of people don't show up. Then,  Success : Men who show up : $p = 80  $% and Failure : Men who didn't show up : $(1-p) = 1 - 80/100 = 20/100$

$\Pr(X \leq 50) = 1 - \Pr(X > 50) = 1 - \sum_{k = 51}^{52} \binom{52}{k}(0.8)^k(0.2)^{52 - k} = 1-[P(X = 51) + P(X = 52)]= 1- [\binom{52}{51}(0.8)^{51}(1 - 0.8)^{52 - 51} + \binom{52}{52}(0.8)^{52}(1 - 0.8)^{52 - 52} ]$